# MySQL Count matching records from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Considering the following 4 tables

```
entity  table1        table2        table3       
------  ------------- ------------- -------------
id      ei(entity.id) ei(entity.id) ei(entity.id)
name    something     somethingelse yetanother
```

**How can I figure out entity usage in all three tables**, represented like

```
---------------------
| id | t1 | t2 | t3 |
---------------------
|  1 | 14 | 23 |  0 |
|  2 | 66 |  9 |  5 |
...
```

My Original approach was to select from entity then left join other tables but MySQL doesn't seem to like it

```
SELECT e.id,count(t1.id) FROM entity AS e LEFT JOIN table1 AS t1 on e.id=t1.ei;
```

Edit: Here is the output for 1 table

```
mysql> explain select e.id,count(o.id) from entity e left join table1 t1 on e.id=o.ei where e.ty=3;
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows  | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | e     | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |  1083 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | o     | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 90201 |             |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-------+-------------+
2 rows in set (0.04 sec)
```

The opposite works much better, but doesn't scale to multiple tables

```
SELECT e.id,count(t1,id) FROM table1 AS t1 LEFT JOIN entity AS e ON t1.ei=e.id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to rewrite this query.

Group and count in each table individually, then join:

```
SELECT  a.id, 
        COALESCE(b.t1, 0) AS t1,
        COALESCE(c.t2, 0) AS t2,
        COALESCE(d.t3, 0) AS t3
FROM
        entity a
    LEFT JOIN
        ( SELECT ei,
                 COUNT(*) AS t1
          FROM table1
          GROUP BY ei
        ) AS b
            ON a.id = b.ei
    LEFT JOIN
        ( SELECT ei,
                 COUNT(*) AS t2
          FROM table2
          GROUP BY ei
        ) AS c
            ON a.id = c.ei
    LEFT JOIN
        ( SELECT ei,
                 COUNT(*) AS t3
          FROM table3
          GROUP BY ei
        ) AS d
            ON a.id = d.ei
  ;
```

---

You should definitely add an index on `(ei)` on each of the 3 tables, if you haven't one.

Comment: Wow. Works wonders. You may want to fix the extra ',' before each FROM

Comment: By the way, without indexes the query takes 0.5s which is perfect for me.

Comment: If you prefer 0.5 over 0.005, it's fine with me. I can't understand why people do not want to put indexes in their tables, that's what they are for, to improve efficiency.

Comment: This particular request is triggered by manual user intervention. Hence everything below 1s is acceptable. I am concerned that additional indexing will slow down batch insertion and add to the overall size, which is more of a concern.

Comment: `entity.id` seems to be the primary key and `tableX.ei` seems to be a foreign key. These should be indexed in general, as there will be used quite often for joins. With current disk space so cheap, why overall size is an issue? Is this to run on a limited device?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  a.ID, 
        COUNT(b.ei) t1,
        COUNT(c.ei) t2,
        COUNT(d.ei) t3
FROM    entity a
        LEFT JOIN table1 b
            ON a.id = b.ei
        LEFT JOIN table2 c
            ON a.id = c.ei
        LEFT JOIN table3 d
            ON a.ID = d.ei
GROUP BY a.ID
```

Comment: I tried and had to kill the query after a minute or so whereas running counts individually takes 0.04s ... I would expect it to take 0.12s(?)

Comment: do you have indexes on this column? `entity.id`, `table1.ei`, `table2.ei`, `table3.ei`? can you post the result `EXPLAIN pasteyourQueyrHere`?

Comment: @MonoThreaded the problem is that you didn't add index on the linking columns, try altering table using this `ALTER TABLE table1 ADD INDEX t1_idx (ei)`, as well as the other tables. and try the query again. is `entity.id` a primary key?

Comment: Unfortunately that is not an option. I am surprised by the fact that inidividual counts are extermely fast. Consolidating 3 results by e.id cannot take that long!

Comment: why altering is not an option? can you add the `explain` which the query joins the three tables? please. It's because you did not have `index` on the columns. See the value of `possible_keys` in explain result.

Answer (score 1):

```
select select 
e.id,
sum(case when t1.name is null then 0 else 1 end) t1,
sum(case when t2.name is null then 0 else 1 end) t2,
sum(case when t3.name is null then 0 else 1 end) t3
from
entity e left join table1 t1 on e.id=t1.ei left join table2 t2 on e.id=t2.ei left join table3 t3 on e.id=t3.ei
group by e.id
```

==

## [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/de307/10)

Comment: This is producing a very long query as well (as in several minutes)